# Insert values from another column

Tags: r, datatable

How I can combine the values ​​of the columns? Like this:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at `rbind`

Comment: Please don't post data like that. Use `?dput` or a text only copy/paste so that we can get the data into an `R` session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option using `rbind`.

```
d <- seq(1, 27)
m <- matrix(d, nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
```

Then `m` would look as follows (mimicking your input data):

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
[2,]   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18
[3,]   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27
```

Then you can call `rbind` on chunks of your input; for bigger matrices you might want to do this in a `for-loop`:

```
mnew = data.frame(rbind(m[, 1:3], m[ ,4:6], m[,7:9]))
names(mnew) <- c('V1', 'V2', 'V3')
```

That yields the desired output:

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  2  3
2 10 11 12
3 19 20 21
4  4  5  6
5 13 14 15
6 22 23 24
7  7  8  9
8 16 17 18
9 25 26 27
```

Answer (score 2):

first you must say which columns you want to combine but you can do it like this considering that dat is the name of your dataframe

```
dt <- data.frame(c(dat$V1,dat$V4,dat$V7),c(dat$V2,dat$V5,dat$V8),c(dat$V3,dat$V6,dat$V9))
```

then rename your columns using `names(dt) <- c("V1","V2","V3")`

Comment: If you want to use `rbind` you must cut your data frame in 3 dataframes then rename columns and use `rbind`

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your basic dataframe is named df1
Using rbind, as Orhan already said, you had to split your dataframe and rename the columns:

```
a <- df1[1:3]
names(a) <- c("V1","V2", "V3")
b <- df1[4:6]
names(b) <- c("V1","V2", "V3")
c <- df1[7:9]
names(c) <- c("V1","V2", "V3")
df2<- rbind(a,b,c)
```

Comment: Similar to mine but also taking care of different names, +1

Answer (score 0):

This could be easily be performed by changing df to á matrix and then using `rbind`

```
df <- as.matrix(df)
df <- rbind(df[,1:3],df[,4:6],df[,7:9])
```

Then you have the option of converting it back to data.frame using as.data.frame()